# How to run a PowerPoint slideshow with OnSlideShowPageChange from command line

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint 2016 pptm / ppsm where I want to run some code on OnSlideShowPageChange. When I start the slideshow from within PowerPoint with the VBA Editor open, the event gets fired.
When I start the slideshow from command line with "...\Powerpnt.exe" /S "...\MySlideShow.pptm", the event is not fired.

Also when I open the slideshow in PowerPoint and do NOT open the VBA editor once, the event is not fired on F5.

What could be the problem?

I tried setting the macro security to lowest, no effect.

This is my code:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal objWindow As SlideShowWindow)

MsgBox "Hello"

End Sub
```

Comment: For reasons unknown, OnSlideShowPageChange doesn't work for some people unless they add an ActiveX control to one of the slides in the presentation. Doesn't have to be on the slide (ie, it can be sitting off the slide) or even visible, as I recall.  Give that a try.